# Regex to add text before and after the match. vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, .net-2.0, vb.net-2010

I have part of string (Sample Below)

```
'another string string string....

"message":"test message 1 abcd xyz"}

"message":"test message 2 123 xyz bla bla"}

"message":"msg message msg etc xyz bla xyz"}

'other string string string....
```

I just want to search each message tag ("message":"msg here"}) and add some text in start and some text at the end of the match like this.

```
'another string string string.... as it is

<bound>"message":"test message 1 abcd xyz"}</bound>

<bound>"message":"test message 2 123 xyz bla bla"}</bound>

<bound>"message":"msg message msg etc xyz bla xyz"}</bound>

'other string string string.... as it is
```

How can I do this with the help of regex?
I Am using visual basic 2010 with targeted platform .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourstr=Regex.Replace(yourstr,@"("")message\1:\1[^\1]*?\1}","<bound>$0</bound>");
```

Comment: I can't Believe this. I was trying this since 4-5 days. You have solve my problem in just 4-5 minutes :-) thank you so much.
Note: VB.net Users do not write "@" before pattren.

Comment: Dear @Tim.Tang My problem is now solved, but Can you please describe your regex pattern step by step?